# Wheel of time: Is it known if some of the hundred companions of Lews Therin are actually heroes of the Horn's reincarnations?

Tags: the-wheel-of-time

> **The Hundred Companions** were a group of one hundred thirteen young male Aes Sedai from the Age of Legends who were very vocal supporters of Lews Therin Telamon's plan of attacking the Bore directly and sealing the Dark One in his prison.

whereas

> **The Heroes of the Horn** are the great heroes of the Pattern, bound to the Horn of Valere. They are summoned to battle to fight for the Light. Sometimes the Wheel adds to their numbers, however it is unknown if heroes can be lost from the ranks.

It is known that Horn also summons approximately hundred or so heroes which are bound to the wheel. The number strikes to me as coincidental?

Is it stated if the companions were actually Heroes of the horn (or some were)?

Comment: It doesn't seem like many (any?) of the heroes bound to the horn can channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not stated in any of the books that I recall, and I actually don't recall a number being mentioned for the Heroes of the Horn, as the OP claims.

Is it "possible" that some of the Companions got bound to the Horn?  Sure.  Is there evidence of that in any canonical source? Not that I know of.

There is definitely not a 1:1 match, because none of the Heroes that is repeatedly mentioned (Birgitte, Gaidal Cain, Hawkwing, etc etc) are channelers of any flavor, hey are just really talented people who become legendary through their exploits.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is hinted at in the conversation Rand has with Hawkwing at Falme, where Artur says he has fought alongside Lews Therin as many times as against, although nothing is ever explicitly mentioned. Check the WoT companion guide, see if there is anything more there, but that's all I can think of that might vaguely reference this.